# Bluetooth on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS does not detect any devices and does not get detected

Tags: bluetooth

I am using a DEll inspiron 3442 and the bluetooth icon is there on the taskbar but it doesn't detect any devices and cannot be detected by my phone either. The Bluetooth on my laptop works - I also have Windows on my phone.

Here is the output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb`

```
06:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
Subsystem: Dell Wireless 1704 802.11n + BT 4.0 [1028:0016]
Kernel driver in use: wl
Kernel modules: bcma, wl
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0a5c:21d7 Broadcom Corp. BCM43142 Bluetooth 4.0
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1bcf:2b8b Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 04ca:0061 Lite-On Technology Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb` terminal command.